# Imported Mist account into newer version of ethereum wallet. I cannot see my custom tokens in the new wallet

Tags: mist, wallets

I just imported my old mist account wich holds two contracts into my new ethereum wallet with the wallet file. My problem is that I cannot seem my tokens after importing, that I've created in the older wallet. How can I get them in my new wallet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a problem - I have a similar issue with my multi-sig wallet contract every time that I update Geth / Mist.

You should just "watch" the contracts again - using the watch contract button on the Contracts page:

[image]

And add the token contract's address and ABI similar to this:

[image]